# Validation for optional parameters in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

How can I validate the data type of optional parameters in ASP.NET Web API?

My routing looks like this:

```csharp
context.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ItemList",
    routeTemplate: "api/v1/projects/{projectId}/items",
    defaults: new
        {
            area = AreaName,
            controller = "Items",
            action = "GetItems",
            offset = RouteParameter.Optional,
            count = RouteParameter.Optional,
        }
);
```

These would all be valid requests:

```
http://localhost/api/v1/projects/1/items  
http://localhost/api/v1/projects/1/items?offset=20  
http://localhost/api/v1/projects/1/items?count=10  
http://localhost/api/v1/projects/1/items?offset=20&count=10
```

Everything works fine except when an invalid value is provided for one of the parameters. For example,

```
http://localhost/api/v1/projects/1/items?count=a
```

There is no validation error, count just becomes null.

Is there a way to detect this and return an error message? I think I recall seeing a solution somewhere with custom message handlers but I cannot find it any more.

The controller method looks like this:

```c#
public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems([FromUri]GetItemsParams getItemsParams)
{
    // logic
}
```

And the params class looks like this:

```c#
[DataContract]
public class GetItemsParams
{
    [DataMember] public int? offset { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public int? count { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll want to add constraints. Constraints are documented [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection), and are used for making sure you have valid input in your path. If a constraint is violated, its as if the controller/action is not matched and therefore not called. Constraints can be RegEx, like the example below, or can be customized by implementing a class with `IRouteConstraint`

For example:

```
context.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ItemList",
    routeTemplate: "api/v1/projects/{projectId}/items",
    defaults: new
        {
            area = AreaName,
            controller = "Items",
            action = "GetItems",
            offset = RouteParameter.Optional,
            count = RouteParameter.Optional,
        },
     constraints: new
        {
            offset = @"\d+",
            count = @"\d+"
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add model validation to your method or controller, and you'll get what you want automatically:

```
[ValidateModel]
public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems([FromUri]GetItemsParams getItemsParams)
{
    // logic
}
```

Now when called with

```
http://localhost/api/v1/projects/1/items?count=a
```

You'll get an error with message:

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"getItemsParams.offset":["The value 'a' is not valid for offset."]}}
```

Read the [complete story about model validation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api).